# YII: HAS_MANY Relation Issue

Tags: activerecord, yii

YII newbie here.

I'm having issues with one-to-many relation.

We have following tables:

```
## users
  uid
  username

## notes
  date
  body

## users_notes
  user_id
  note_id
```

We got two models - Users:

```
'usersNotes' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UsersNotes', 'user_id'),
```

and Notes:

```
'usersNotes' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UsersNotes', 'note_id'),
```

Of course we also have a model for pivot table - users_notes:

```
return array(
            'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'user_id'),
            'note' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Notes', 'note_id'),
        );
```

When trying to display notes in a foreach loop we're getting an error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` in this line `foreach($this->_pkAlias as $name=>$alias)` of `/framework/db/ar/CActiveFinder.php(838)` file.

Do you have any ideas? Is there something we're missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem, you have a relation like "One user has multiple notes". In that case, you don't need a third table. Notes just needs one foreign key pointing to user_id in the Users table.

In case you need a many to many relation, just tell us.

Comment: I noticed this before (just over engineered my db) however your answer is correct. Thanks.

Comment: Great then. Glad to help you!